# MySql , How to select the not repeated rows only

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 100 000 record, I want to select only the none repeated.

In another word, if the row are duplicated did not show it at all

```
ID     Name    Reslut
1      Adam    10
2      Mark    10
3      Mark    10
```

result

```
ID     Name    Reslut
1      Adam    10
```

any ideas ?

Comment: `GROUP BY Reslut` or by `Name` depending on which one you want/dont want. But am pretty sure that should read as `Result`, right? (typo?)

Comment: What defines if the rows are the same? Is it name and result*? Or just one of the rows? What if there are 2 identical Names with different Results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join a query on the table with a query that groups by the name only returns the unique names:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable t
JOIN   (SELECT   name
        FROM     mytable
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1) s ON t.name = s.name
```

Comment: Sorry I update my question so it would be more clear, can you see it now ?

Comment: So if the same name has multiple results, do you want to show it or not?

Comment: @marvillous edited my query to fit your edited question, although the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same set :

```
ID     Name    Result
1      Adam    10
2      Mark    10
3      Mark    10
4      Mark    20
```

I'm guessing the final solution would be:

```
ID     Name    Result
1      Adam    10
4      Mark    20
```

Using the above query previously suggested I modified it to take the result into consideration:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM myTable t1
JOIN 
   (
      SELECT name, result 
      FROM myTable  
      GROUP BY name, result 
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) t2
WHERE 
    t1.name=t2.name and 
    t1.result = t2.result;
```